# how to make custom C# ComboBoxItem that inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control? if possible?

Tags: c#, inheritance, combobox

I need to create custom comboboxitem wich i can process among other controls that inherit System.Windows.Forms.Control class. So my comboboxitem must inherit System.Windows.Forms.Control because i use cast to that type and refer to Text property withn a loop.
There is some posts on how to create custom item but that one inherits Object class which is not working for me? I tried but it didnt work?Here is my try:

```
public class ComboItem : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public override  string Text { get; set; }
    // public object Value { get; set; }
    public ComboItem(string text) { this.Text = text; }
    public ComboItem(string text, string value) { this.Text = text; this.Value = value; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

nothing is displayed in combo box after following code

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboItem asd = new ComboItem("qweqwwqeq");
        ComboItem asd2 = new ComboItem("2222222");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(asd);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(asd2);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    }
```

this is context in which i need to use it:

```
     System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)asd["Kontrola"];                
  ctrl.Text = (String)asd["Engleski"];
```

Comment: Do you understand what a `Control` is? It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Why on earth you would inherit a ComboboxItem from `Control`?

Comment: _Why on earth you would inherit a ComboboxItem from Control?_ A valid question. OTOH: Why not? Using classes for ComboBox Items is quite normal and the ComboBoxItems are as good a place to store a few Controls as any, one could assume.. The class has a ToString method, so why is nothing displayed? Other than the missing displaystring the Controls from the combobox Items work just fine: you can add them to the Form and use them..

Comment: @TaW What do you mean? I'm not against using `ComboBoxItem` class, Why do you need to inherit it from control? If at all you need to store some control in it, you can wrap it in your class. Inheriting from `Control` makes no sense.

Comment: Well, sense or not, one may still wonder, just why the wrapper is needed? I guess stopping it from using the ToString __here__ it is more or less an accidental decision deep inside the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are not really talking about the `ComboBoxItem Class`, which is from `WPF` but simply of the `Winforms Combobox` which contains `objects`.

For some reason Controls don't get displayed in Collections unless they are actually placed in a Container Control.

So you probably have to wrap your Control in a minimal wrapper class like this:

```
class CtlWrapper
{
    public Control theControl { get; private set; }
    public CtlWrapper(string text)
    {
        theControl = new Control();
        theControl.Text = text;
    }
    public CtlWrapper(Control control) { theControl = control; } // for fun
    public override string ToString() { return theControl.Text; }
}
```

Not sure what you'll do with such a generic thing as Control in the ComboBox's Items list, but maybe you'll add some code to create different Control types..? With the wrapper the ToString text gets displayed as expected..

Of course you an add a Value string or whatever you need to the class as needed or you could use your own class as the type  of 'theControl'..

Edit: For fun I have added a 2nd constructor to allow for adding existing Controls (of any type ;-)

Comment: I wasnt talking about' ComboBoxItem' Clas and your answer works and it gets displayed text in combo box and tankh you:)  But it must not be wrapped beacause of the way i use it. It has to be inherited from 'Control' class.

Comment: I have a 'DataTable" which stores labels, groupboxes etc, all of which are 'Control' inherited in first column. Other columns hold translations for Controls text fields. So table is used to switch label and group boxes texts  to onother langugas. I need to translate combo box items also on wich i Cannot use this cast obviously '((System.Windows.Forms.Control)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Text' beacuse it is not iinherting 'Control' class. I kniw there might be more elegant solutions to this, but i just stuck to this one and want to see now can it be done this way:)

Comment: Well, with enough parenthesis sprinkled over the code I'm pretty sure you can get this to work. But instead of `((System.Windows.Forms.Control) comboBox1.SelectedItem).Text'` you can simply write `( (CtlWrapper) comboBox1.SelectedItem ).theControl.Text`

Comment: Yes, but then what about other controls in table which are not CtlWrapper instances. Table is accessed with foreach loop? more precisly:`ComboItem asd = new ComboItem("qweqwwqeq"); and for iinstance Label ll = new Label("some text")` are stored inn a table and has to inherit control so i access all of them with same Cast from within foreachloop.

Comment: `            foreach(DataRow asd in prevodiTablica.Rows)
            {               
                        System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)asd["Kontrola"];                
                        ctrl.Text = (String)asd["Engleski"];                 
            }`

Comment: Yes, for such a loop you'll have to include a type check, e.g. `if (comboBox1.SelectedItem is CtlWrapper) .. else .. `

Comment: I will, i had togught of that, but I just wanted that comboItem to be inherted form Control class :P :) Thanks again!